# Python stacked bar chart with multiple series

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, bokeh, seaborn

I need to create a chart like the one below, a series of stacked bars. Some values are positive and some are negative. I would like the chart to be displayed just like the stacked bar chart from excel, which stacks positives values up and negative values down.
Is there a straightforward method to do this for N number of categories?

Here is some example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['06-11-2018', '06-12-2018', '06-13-2018', '06-14-2018', '06-15-2018'], 
                  data={'A': [-378, -2347, 509, 987, 513], 
                        'B': [-527, -2599, 765, 533, 670], 
                        'C': [-2343, -2273, 2093, 2197, 1990], 
                        'D': [-1845, -1853, 3325, 1306, 2160]})
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data frame's `plot` function handles negative values in the way you describe.  If we change some of the values in the data frame to be negative the line

```
df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

gives us this chart:

[image: Stacked bar chart with negative values]

We can add a 'total' line similar to the black line in the question's image by summing the rows of the data frame and plotting the returned `Series` object on the same `axes` as the bar chart:

[image: Stacked bar chart with total line]

The code that generated this second chart is below.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(index=['06-11-2018', '06-12-2018', '06-13-2018',
                         '06-14-2018', '06-15-2018'], 
                  data={'A': [-378, 2347, 509, 987, 513], 
                        'B': [527, 2599, -765, 533, 670], 
                        'C': [2343, -2273, 2093, -2197, 1990], 
                        'D': [1845, 1853, -3325, 1306, 2160]})

ax = df.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
df.sum(axis=1).plot(ax=ax, color="k")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but is there a way to draw a "total" line over this chart? I've tried using the `axes` object that the `.plot()` method returns, but with no success.

Comment: @GustavoAmarante Sure, assuming you've assigned the returned `axes` object to a variable called `ax` you can do `df.sum(axis=1).plot(ax=ax, color="k")` (I specified the colour of the line because without this it returns to the beginning of the colour cycle, and that blue has already been used on the bars).

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working. The code runs without any errors or warnings, but the chart simply does not update. I've tried reversing the order (ploting the line first, and then the bars) but the same thing happens, it does not update for the second series.

Comment: @GustavoAmarante I've edited the answer to show the total line.  See how your code compares with mine: if it's the same and you still can't see the line I think you're at the point of asking a new question.